# Make a photo a link and then pass the photo id so that the next page presents information about that specific photo

Tags: php, facebook, photo

This is the  code. editor.php is the link. photo_id is the the information i want to pass over. $photo['picture'] is the photo.

```
     print ('<a href="editor.php?photo_id='.$photo['id'].'"><img src='{$photo['picture']}'.'</a>'./>');
```

Comment: Gonna need more information. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I used the $_GET['photo_id'] to get the id... The only problem is at the code above. I believe there is something wrong with the brackets.. I have managed to do it for a normal link but not a photo link >>>>   print ('<a href="albumPhotos.php?album_id='.$album['id'].'">'.$album['name'].'</a>'.'</br>' ) ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `session_start();` and put you  link in a `$_SESSION['last_link'];` and use the same function on the next page and access the value you  have put in `$_SESSION['last_link']` to get information about the photo and display it.

[PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Or, if you used that kind of link, in the `editor.php` you can use `$_GET['photo_id']` to get the id of your photo, after the user have clicked on the image to follow the link.

Edit 1:
You could try putting the right concatenation:

try this:
`echo '<a href="editor.php?photo_id='.$photo['id'].'"><img src='.$photo['picture'].' /></a>';`

Comment: yes i did that.. That is working fine.. Im just having errors with the specific code here!! There must be e problem with the brackets or something like that.. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @EiriniTelevantou please try and learn a little bit more about php :)